# Add total row to dataframe with multi level index

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the follow dataframe with a multi level index:

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   index=arrays)
```

All I'm trying to do is add a 'Totals' row to the bottom (12, 15, 18 would be the expected values here). It seems like I need to calculate the totals and then append them to the dataframe, but I just can't get it work while preserving the multi level index (which I want to do). Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.loc[('Total',)] = df.sum()`

Comment: Tweaked this to `df.loc[('Total',' ')] = df.sum()`. It correctly inserted the 'Total' row, but with nans instead of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks for the responses. Those plus a little more education about indices in Python got me to something that worked.

```
# Create df of totals
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.sum())
# Transpose df
df2 = df2.T
# Reset index
df2 = df2.reset_index()
# Add additional column so the columns of df2 match the columns of df
df2['Index'] = "zTotal"
# Set indices to match df indices
df2 = df2.set_index(['index', 'Index'])
# Concat df and df2
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2])
# Sort in desired order
df3 = df3.sort_index(ascending=[False,True])
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not preserve your multi-level index, but it does append a new row called "total" that contains column sums:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz']),
          np.array(['one', 'two', 'one'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]), 
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   index=arrays)

df.append(df.sum().rename('total')).assign(total=lambda d: d.sum(1))
```

Comment: That works, but I'd prefer to preserve the multi-level index. Maybe I can pull the combined index values apart after running this? This is my first experience with multi-level indexing.

Comment: How will the summary row fit into the context of the multi-level index?

Comment: At the bottom as a grand total. I'm trying to mimic the format of a data-entry screen, which is why I'm particular about how it looks.