# Adding a total per level-2 index in a multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe:

```
df_full = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'B',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Books',
  1: 'Candy',
  2: 'Pencil',
  3: 'Table',
  4: 'PC',
  5: 'Printer',
  6: 'Lamp',
  7: 'Books',
  8: 'Candy',
  9: 'Pencil',
  10: 'Table',
  11: 'PC',
  12: 'Printer',
  13: 'Lamp'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_1'): {0: 9.937449997200002, 1: 30.71300000639998, 2: 58.81199999639999, 3: 25.661999978399994, 4: 3.657999996, 5: 12.0879999972, 6: 61.16600000040001, 7: 6.319439989199998, 8: 12.333119997600003, 9: 24.0544100028, 10: 24.384659998799997, 11: 1.9992000012000002, 12: 0.324, 13: 40.69122000000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_2'): {0: 21.890370397789923, 1: 28.300470581874837, 2: 53.52039700062155, 3: 52.425508769690694, 4: 6.384936971649232, 5: 6.807138946302334, 6: 52.172, 7: 5.916852561, 8: 5.810764652, 9: 12.1243325, 10: 17.88071596, 11: 0.913782413, 12: 0.869207661, 13: 20.9447844},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'last_week_sales'): {0: np.nan,
  1: np.nan,
  2: np.nan,
  3: np.nan,
  4: np.nan,
  5: np.nan,
  6: np.nan,
  7: np.nan,
  8: np.nan,
  9: np.nan,
  10: np.nan,
  11: np.nan,
  12: np.nan,
  13: np.nan},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 86.0,
  1: 66.0,
  2: 188.0,
  3: 556.0,
  4: 12.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 56.0,
  7: 90.0,
  8: 26.0,
  9: 49.0,
  10: 250.0,
  11: 7.0,
  12: 2.0,
  13: 44.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 4390.11,
  1: 24825.059999999998,
  2: 48592.39999999998,
  3: 60629.77,
  4: 831.22,
  5: 1545.71,
  6: 34584.99,
  7: 5641.54,
  8: 6798.75,
  9: 13290.13,
  10: 42692.68000000001,
  11: 947.65,
  12: 329.0,
  13: 29889.65},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_1'): {0: 13.690399997999998, 1: 38.723000005199985, 2: 72.4443400032, 3: 36.75802000560001, 4: 5.691999996, 5: 7.206999998399999, 6: 66.55265999039996, 7: 6.4613199911999954, 8: 12.845630001599998, 9: 26.032340003999998, 10: 30.1634600016, 11: 1.0203399996, 12: 1.4089999991999997, 13: 43.67116000320002},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'),
  'Sales_2'): {0: 22.874363860953647, 1: 29.5726042895728, 2: 55.926190956481534, 3: 54.7820864335212, 4: 6.671946105284065, 5: 7.113126469779095, 6: 54.517, 7: 6.194107518, 8: 6.083562133, 9: 12.69221484, 10: 18.71872129, 11: 0.956574175, 12: 0.910216433, 13: 21.92632044},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'last_week_sales'): {0: 4390.11,
  1: 24825.059999999998,
  2: 48592.39999999998,
  3: 60629.77,
  4: 831.22,
  5: 1545.71,
  6: 34584.99,
  7: 5641.54,
  8: 6798.75,
  9: 13290.13,
  10: 42692.68000000001,
  11: 947.65,
  12: 329.0,
  13: 29889.65},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 109.0,
  1: 48.0,
  2: 174.0,
  3: 587.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 5.0,
  6: 43.0,
  7: 62.0,
  8: 13.0,
  9: 37.0,
  10: 196.0,
  11: 8.0,
  12: 1.0,
  13: 33.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-05 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 3453.02,
  1: 17868.730000000003,
  2: 44707.82999999999,
  3: 60558.97999999999,
  4: 1261.0,
  5: 1914.6000000000001,
  6: 24146.09,
  7: 6201.489999999999,
  8: 5513.960000000001,
  9: 9645.87,
  10: 25086.785,
  11: 663.0,
  12: 448.61,
  13: 26332.7}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

I am trying to get a `total` for each column per `category`. So in this `df` example adding 2 lines below `Lamp` denoting the totals of each column. Red lines indicate the desired `totals` placement:

[image]

What I've tried:

```
df_out['total'] = df_out.sum(level=1).loc[:, (slice(None), 'total_sales')]
```

But get:

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

I also checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61239640/add-total-row-to-dataframe-with-multi-level-index) but could not apply it to my self.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` on `level=0`

```
s = df_full.groupby(level=0).sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s.index, ['Total']])

df_out = df_full.append(s).sort_index()
```

---

```
print(df_out)
                           2021-06-28 00:00:00                                                      2021-07-05 00:00:00                                                     
                           Sales_1     Sales_2 last_week_sales total_orders total_sales             Sales_1     Sales_2 last_week_sales total_orders total_sales
group category                                                                                                                                                  
A     Books                9.93745   21.890370             NaN         86.0     4390.11            13.69040   22.874364         4390.11        109.0    3453.020
      Candy               30.71300   28.300471             NaN         66.0    24825.06            38.72300   29.572604        24825.06         48.0   17868.730
      Lamp                61.16600   52.172000             NaN         56.0    34584.99            66.55266   54.517000        34584.99         43.0   24146.090
      PC                   3.65800    6.384937             NaN         12.0      831.22             5.69200    6.671946          831.22         13.0    1261.000
      Pencil              58.81200   53.520397             NaN        188.0    48592.40            72.44434   55.926191        48592.40        174.0   44707.830
      Printer             12.08800    6.807139             NaN          4.0     1545.71             7.20700    7.113126         1545.71          5.0    1914.600
      Table               25.66200   52.425509             NaN        556.0    60629.77            36.75802   54.782086        60629.77        587.0   60558.980
      Total              202.03645  221.500823             0.0        968.0   175399.26           241.06742  231.457318       175399.26        979.0  153910.250
B     Books                6.31944    5.916853             NaN         90.0     5641.54             6.46132    6.194108         5641.54         62.0    6201.490
      Candy               12.33312    5.810765             NaN         26.0     6798.75            12.84563    6.083562         6798.75         13.0    5513.960
      Lamp                40.69122   20.944784             NaN         44.0    29889.65            43.67116   21.926320        29889.65         33.0   26332.700
      PC                   1.99920    0.913782             NaN          7.0      947.65             1.02034    0.956574          947.65          8.0     663.000
      Pencil              24.05441   12.124332             NaN         49.0    13290.13            26.03234   12.692215        13290.13         37.0    9645.870
      Printer              0.32400    0.869208             NaN          2.0      329.00             1.40900    0.910216          329.00          1.0     448.610
      Table               24.38466   17.880716             NaN        250.0    42692.68            30.16346   18.718721        42692.68        196.0   25086.785
      Total              110.10605   64.460440             0.0        468.0    99589.40           121.60325   67.481717        99589.40        350.0   73892.415
```

Comment: That works, thank you! And if I wanted to have a `total` of all of the df at the very end?

Comment: We could try `df_out.loc[('all', 'total'), :] = df_full.sum()`